# Minimum number of candies to add to have a equitable distribution

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We are given candies of different types represented by an array `arr`, such that arr[i] is the number of candies of type i. Now, we need to place these candies in some packets, which a minimum number of packets being 2, such that in each packet, we have an equal number of candies of the same type. Now, whenever such a distribution is impossible, we can add some candies. Now, we must report the minimum number of candies to be added.

For example:
if `arr = [1, 3, 4]`
We can have additional candies as [1, 1, 0] such that the final array becomes [2, 4, 4]. Thus dividing it into two packets is possible, such that the distribution of candy in each is [1, 2, 2].
if `arr = [3, 3, 3, 3, 2]`. Then adding just a single candy to the last type suffices.

The best solution I came up with was a simple brute force. I guess we can improve it by using only primes. But, that can't help much I guess. Is there better way to do it?

```
int mx = *max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
int mn = 1e9;
for (int sz = 2; sz <= mx; sz++) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int &x: arr) cnt += (sz - (x % sz)) % sz;
    mn = min(mn, cnt);
}
cout << mn << endl;
```

Comment: Also you can break once `sz - min_element > mn`, not sure about other optimizations.

Comment: What is the range of values for `arr[i]`? And what is the maximum number of candy types possible?

Comment: Please share the constraints as well.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur The constraints were small enough that my brute force would pass. I just wanted to ask if we had any better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

**Optimization**

We can do some pruning to avoid having to consider every single number within the range; in fact, it's provable that the only candidates for the packet size (number of packets) are prime numbers that appear as factors in the original array, or 2.

**Why?**

- The problem seems to be equivalent to finding the minimum number of increments to any element in the array such that all elements are divisible by at least a single number, the number of packets, `g > 1`.
- [Abhinav Mathur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76721121/14789065) explains why `g` ought to be prime.
- For an array with `N` candies, the minimum number of increments needed is bounded above by `N`- select `g = 2` and increment candies of an odd denominations once, of which there can be at most `N`. So first select `g = 2` as a baseline.
- Proof by contradiction: Assume that for the best number of packets `g' > 2`, no elements in the array are divisible by it. Because no elements are divisible by it initially, we need to increment every element at least once, hence the number of increments for `g'` is `N' >= N`. However, we showed above that for `2`, the number of increments needed is bounded above by `N`. It follows that `g'` can, at best, be tied with selecting `g = 2` instead.

**Code**

Quick test in Python3; does use `sympy` for prime factorization but unrolling another implementation would work fine.

```
import random
from collections import Counter
from sympy.ntheory import factorint

def original(A):
    """
    Starts to struggle for arrays of size 100 with limits between 1 and 1e6
    """
    mx = max(A)
    mn = 1e9
    for sz in range(2, mx + 1):
        cnt = 0
        for x in A:
            cnt += (sz - (x % sz)) % sz

        mn = min(mn, cnt)

    return mn


def faster(A):
    """
    Does some pruning and seems to remain performant
    """
    N = len(A)
    F = [factorint(x) for x in A] # factorint(x) gives a dict where key is the factor, value is the multiplicity
    factor_counts = Counter()
    for factor in F:
        for f in factor:
            factor_counts[f] += 1

    # how many odd elements are there? this is our baseline
    n_odd = N - factor_counts[2]
    res = n_odd

    # Provable that if there is a better prime factor than 2, it needs to be present in the original
    # now we care only about factors that appear at least N - res + 1 times
    for factor, frq in factor_counts.items():
        if frq < N - res + 1:
            continue

        # compute cost of using factor
        cost = 0
        for x in A:
            cost += ((factor - (x % factor)) % factor)

        res = min(res, cost)

    return res

def test(A):
    act, exp = original(A), faster(A)
    if act == exp:
        return 0

    print(f"For {A} expected {act} but got {exp}")
    return 1


def small_tests():
    """
    20 random arrays of sizes between 10-30 with numbers <= 500
    """
    res = [
        [random.randint(1, 500) for _ in range(10, 30)]
        for __ in range(20)
    ]

    # print(f"Example of an small array: {res[7]}")
    return res


def mostly_odd():
    res = [
        [2 * random.randint(1, 100) + 1 for _ in range(10, 30)] + [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(5)]
        for __ in range(20)
    ]

    # print(f"Example of an odd array: {res[7]}")
    return res


def main():
    tests = [
        [1, 3, 4],
        [2, 4, 17],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
        [30, 90]
    ] + small_tests() + mostly_odd()
    errors, total = 0, 0
    for A in tests:
        errors += test(A)
        total += 1

    print(f"{total - errors} / {total} passed")
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you please add the proof for _"it's provable that the only candidates for the packet size are prime numbers that appear as factors in the original array"_?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur what's the solution for [17, 31]?

Comment: @גלעדברקן it will be 2. The array would be `[18,32]`.

Comment: Added proof; it's pretty short but the TLDR for it is that if picking a prime number for the number of packets won't be any better than picking 2 instead.

Comment: "the only candidates for the packet size (number of packets) are prime numbers that appear as factors in the original array" -- this is a false statement. Easily disproven by the input [17, 31].

Comment: Oops, the statement should have been "the only candidates ... are prime numbers that appear as factors **or 2**". Stated incorrectly but the code/algorithm was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is supposed to be rather straightforward, with just a couple of key observations:

1. Ideally, the packet size will always be a prime number (You can easily prove this by contradiction). While testing out the packet sizes, instead of iterating on `[2, max]`, you can iterate on `primes in range [2, max]`.
2. The minimum number of candies required would be 0 (when all elements have GCD > 1).
3. The maximum number of candies required would be `= number of odd elements in the array` (you can add 1 to each odd number and make them even. The packet size becomes `2` in that case). This condition can be   used to check for an early exit while iterating on the array for a particular packet size.

With these optimisations, I think your approach will be better than "brute force" since you won't test the entire sample space anymore.